# Error occurs SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a request to retrieve data from two tables. The number of columns is the same. But for some reason, an error occurs that says that the select has a different number of columns. And when you make a query for one table, everything is fine.

```
$asks = \DB::table('asks')
->select('id', 'user_id', 'text', 'price', 'ask_id', 'created_at')
->where('user_id', 125)
->union(\DB::table('my_requests')
->select('id', 'user_id', 'text', 'price', 'ask_id', 'created_at')
->where('user_id', 125))
->paginate(10);
```

When I fix on get everything is fine but paginate doesn't work

Comment: Are you pretty sure both tables have all this columns with equal types?

Comment: yes are the same

Comment: Which Laravel version you use?

Comment: version laravel 5.5

Comment: sorry version laravel 5.2.45

Comment: what do you get with `$asks = \DB::table('asks')->...->union(\DB::table('my_requests')->...->where('user_id', 125))->toSql(); dd($asks);`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are following these 2 conditions:

First, the number and the orders of columns that appear in all SELECT statements must be the same. This seems to be correct in your code.

Second, the data types of columns must be the same or compatible.
Are the data types the same? Check that all things related to the tables are the same.
You may want to export the database, then check that the structure is the same exactly for both tables and fields.

Also try the code directly like this to see if it is something in the framework code you are using.

```
SELECT id
FROM asks
UNION
SELECT id
FROM my_requests
LIMIT 10;
```

This allows you to see if the error is in the database or the code.
If the above query works directly in phpmyadmin sql query editor or equivalent program.

```
Try this as well:
$first = DB::table('asks')
->select('id', 'user_id', 'text', 'price', 'ask_id', 'created_at')
->where('user_id', 125);
 
$asks = DB::table('my_requests')
->select('id', 'user_id', 'text', 'price', 'ask_id', 'created_at')
->where('user_id', 125)
->union($first)
->get();

$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$paginate = 5;

$slice = array_slice($asks->toArray(), $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
$result = Paginator::make($slice, count($asks), $paginate);

return View::make('yourView',compact('result'));
```

Comment: I verified that the database query is processed with all tables

Comment: Also checked all data types they are the same

Comment: I also checked all tables one by one as you said if you make a query with one table it works but if you make more than one table an error occurs.

Comment: Did you try this?
SELECT id
FROM asks
UNION
SELECT id
FROM my_requests
LIMIT 10;

Comment: I edited my above answer and added somehting new, please check it.

Comment: SELECT id FROM просит UNION SELECT id FROM my_requests LIMIT 10 its work

Comment: And your new answer unfortunately also throws an error

Comment: I updated my answer, try the last solution. I added ->get() before ->paginate();

Comment: now shows paginate() member function call on array

Comment: Remove paginate, or add the ->get() after paginate.

Comment: put after and deleted still the same error

Comment: if just get it works but i need breakdown

Comment: I added more code above. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is Laravel issue for version <= 5.7, when `paginate` don't work with `union`, see here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21958

You need to use custom paginator (load all results and paginate it after, or some library like https://github.com/krossroad/laravel-unionpaginator), or update your dependencies versions